# In Perl, why can't I bless a variable which contains a reference to a literal?

Tags: perl, reference

I've been trying to learn Perl for a few days, and am still frequently surprised and sometimes mystified at how and why it does things.  Here is my latest puzzle: why are the following two blocks of code not equivalent?

```
my $thing = '';
bless \$thing; # class is implicit
```

versus

```
my $thing = \'';
bless $thing; # class again implicit
```

The second form says "Modification of a read-only value attempted" on the second line.

Comment: Years later, I have learned about `Devel::Peek` and now I'm less confused (maybe).  I though that `\''` is somehow a fundamentally different kind of creature than `\$thing`.  But it turns out they are both references to strings!  The only difference seems to be that in one case the string has the "read-only" flag set, and in the other case it does not.  So what really seems to be going on here is vaguely C++-ish: literals are read-only, and assigning to a variable creates a mutable copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\''` is a reference to a literal.

`\$thing` is a reference to `$thing`. The value of `$thing` is set to the empty string at the moment.

The reason for the error you are getting is the same as the reason the following will give you the same error:

```
my $thing = \5;
$$thing = 10;
```

`bless` modifies the thing to which its first argument refers. In this case, and in yours, `$x` refers to something that is not modifiable.

See [perldoc perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Objects-Are-Blessed;-Variables-Are-Not):

> **Objects Are Blessed; Variables Are Not**
>
> When we `bless` something, we are not blessing the variable which contains a reference to that thing, nor are we blessing the reference that the variable stores; we are blessing ***the thing that the variable refers to*** (sometimes known as the *referent*). (*emphasis mine*)

If you want a class backed by a scalar, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10;

package MyString;

use strict; use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, $self) = @_;
    bless \$self => $class;
}

sub content { ${$_[0] }
sub length { length ${$_[0]} }

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

my $string => MyString->new("Hello World");

say $string->$_ for qw(content length);
```

Of course, you need to exercise discipline and not modify instance data through the backdoor as in `$$string = "Bye bye cruel world"`.

Comment: That was a typo in my question.  My original code didn't have a stray apostrophe.  Fixing question now.  Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Okay, your example with 5 and 10 really did the trick for me.  You're saying that my broken code is trying to do `${\5}=10`, which certainly looks very suspicious.  But!  The following analogous code works just fine: `@{[5]} = (10)`.  Does this mean that there is some difference in the treatment of scalar literals that doesn't apply to the other basic types?

Comment: `@{[]}=()` is not analogous. `[]` is a reference to an anonymous array. An array is a modifiable data structure even if it is anonymous. With [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) installed, try: `const my $x => [1]; @$x = ()`.

Comment: Aha!  So the difference is that scalars are immutable!  Which means my attempt at making a class backed by a string was misguided from the start.  Right?

Comment: Scalar variables are not immutable. Scalar literals just like list literals are. Try `(1,2,3)[1] = 5`.

Comment: You can of course have class backed by a string. `my ($class, $self) = @_; bless \$self => $class`.

Comment: Okay, things are beginning to make sense, though it is a bit bizarre from a Python mindset and from a C++ mindset.  Let me see if I got this right.  Literals are always immutable, and so a reference to a literal is a reference to a constant, and thus can't be changed, because changing the number 5 makes no sense.  Assigning a literal to variable tells Perl to assign the literal a place to live.  Now taking a reference to this variable gives you a perfectly good mutable object.  Is this about right?

Comment: See also [Non-hash objects in `perldoc perlobj`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Non-Hash-Objects).

Comment: Okay, thanks!  I would really love to have diagram, but I don't know how to explain what diagram I want, and this interface is not conducive to drawing them anyway.  You've answered my original question and several more along the way.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that Non-hash objects link.  I found it totally unhelpful.  Oh well.

Comment: `[]` copies all that you put in it.  just as `$x=1; $y=[$x]; $y[0]=2` does not set `$x` to 2, `$y=[5]; $y[0]=6` does not set the constant 5 to 6; instead when the array is created it has a single new scalar element whose value is set to 5, and that new scalar is what is modified.

Comment: @Mark VY, `[ ]` creates a new array. `[ 5 ]` is roughly equivalent to `do { my @anon = 5; \@anon }`. That means the scalar equivalent of `@{[5]} = 10;` is `${ do { my $anon = 5; \$anon } } = 10;`, not `${ \5 } = 10;`. Conversely, the array equivalent of `${ \5 } = 10;` would be `use Readonly; Readonly::Array my @a => 5; @{ \@a } = 10;`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit, I think.  I wish there were a bit more symmetry with respect to when a new object gets created implicitly and when not.

Answer (score 4):

The `bless` operator works *through* a reference: it is the referenced object that becomes blessed. Most often the referenced data is a hash, but as you've found it may also be a scalar or any other Perl data type

```
my $thing = '';
bless \$thing; # class is implicit
```

This is fine. You are setting `$thing` to an empty string (which is irrelevant here) and you are blessing it by passing a reference to it to `bless`

```
my $thing = \'';
bless $thing; # class again implicit
```

This sets `$thing` to a *reference* to a string constant, so the `bless` is then attempting to work on that constant which is impossible because, as the message says, it is read-only

In short, in the first case you are blessing the scalar variable `$thing` while in the second case you are trying to bless string constant `''` which fails